# Invalid statement. Please check aliases, field identifiers, projections and query conditions

Tags: java, dynamic, cloud

I'm using Dynamicloud and something is wrong in my code.

**This is my code:**

```
DynamicProvider<ContactForm> provider = new DynamicProviderImpl<ContactForm>(new RecordCredential(csk, aci));

contactFormModel.setBoundClass(ContactForm.class);
Query<ContactForm> query = provider.createQuery(contactFormModel);

try {
    RecordResults<ContactForm> list = query.add(Conditions.like("contact.namef", "ProBusiness%")).list();
    System.out.println("list = " + list.getFastReturnedSize());

    if (list.getFastReturnedSize() > 0) {
        System.out.println("Contact Name = " + list.getRecords().get(0).getName());
        System.out.println("Contact Comments = " + list.getRecords().get(0).getComments());
    }

} catch (DynamicloudProviderException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**This code throws the following Exception:**

```
org.dynamicloud.exception.DynamicloudProviderException: Invalid statement.  Please check aliases, field identifiers, projections and query conditions.
```

What's wrong?

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hi**

The problems is the `contact` word right before `namef` in your like condition.

**Dynamicloud API provides a method to set the alias of a model.  For example, the aliases are used in situations where you need to execute JOINS**

The problem is solved by calling the method `setAlias` from the query object `query.setAlias("contact")`

```
query.setAlias("contact");
```

[Dynamicloud resources about Query class](https://github.com/dynamicloud/dynamicloud_java_api#query-class)

**Hope this helps**